# what's >> in python dis output?

Tags: python, disassembly

i have the following code

```
code = '''
    x = ['a','b','c']
    for each in x:
        print(each)
    '''
```

I used python's `dis` function of `dis` package and got the following output

```
dis.dis(code)

>   2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('a')
>               2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('b')
>               4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('c')
>               6 BUILD_LIST               3
>               8 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
> 
>   3          10 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 32)
>              12 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
>              14 GET_ITER
>         >>   16 FOR_ITER                12 (to 30)
>              18 STORE_NAME               1 (each)
> 
>   4          20 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
>              22 LOAD_NAME                1 (each)
>              24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
>              26 POP_TOP
>              28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
>         >>   30 POP_BLOCK
>         >>   32 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
>              34 RETURN_VALUE
```

I am wondering what's the significance of `>>` in this output. its being printed for `FOR_ITER`, `POP_BLOCK`, `LOAD_CONST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look for the byte offsets you will observe that each of the tagged lines is the object of a jump or other branching operation. It's supposed to help you identify loop scopes and the like more easily.